# How can i test a microcontroller circuitry based on software?

Tags: msp430, testing, in-circuit

Im attempting to write software to test circuits developed on a MSP430f5xx uC. Testing of circuits could be section wise based on the functionality of sections of circuit. I need to ensure the correctness of circuits with my software before i load it with production software. I googled a bit on the same topic but nothing specific i could find yet.  What are the things to be kept in mind when i write software to test hardware circuits? IS there any reference avialble on this regard?

Comment: Question is a bit vague, perhaps you could explain what you are attempting to do, and what you have explored so far?

Comment: Do you mean the performance of the uC? (e.g. like the DMIPS test code) or the actual hardware configuration for a prototype uC? (e.g. using an HDL such as Verilog)

Comment: I have a board with MSP430f5xxx, i need to write a firmware to test the circuitry. Its kind of Software based self test SBST. Not looking for the performance of the uC, rather correctness of the circuit through firmware.

Comment: Im attempting to write software to test circuits developed on a MSP430f5xx uC. Testing of circuits could be section wise. I need to ensure the correctness of circuits with my software before i load it with production software. I googled a bit on the same topic but nothing specific i could find yet. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify, instead of adding comments.

Comment: Start by thinking about the kinds of things that it absolutely must do, and the kinds of things that could go wrong.  Then think creatively about which error cases you could detect with the circuit unchanged, which could be detected with a simple test harness doing things like looping outputs back to inputs, and which would require a complicated test rig to generate or analyze custom signals (sometimes you can adapt a spare product).  Then present your finding to whoever controls the time & materials budget and explain what kind of coverage is available for what sort of effort/expenditure.

Answer (score 1):

You wont find any answers on the internet because it is very specific to whatever circuits you have connected to the microcontroller.

We have no idea what you have hooked up to the microcontroller so we cant help with testing it.  You or whomever designed these circuits should have defined how they work.  You take that definition and make sure it works.  For example if there is a DAC hooked up you need to follow the procedure for setting a value in the dac and use some sort of measurement device to measure the analog output of the dac and verify it is within range of what you expect.

Not impossible but rare that whatever is hooked up out there is done in such a way that you can have a completely closed self test, meaning the microcontroller can completely test the external circuit without the need of any other test equipment.  If the stuff is designed for that, great, then just do it.  Set the peripheral to do something the examine the feedback to verify it did that something.  If you dont have a setup like this then you need to have some external (to the microcontroller and this outside the microcontroller stuff) that verifies what you told it to do, happened.  How do you do that?  It is extremely specific to whatever this stuff is that you have outside the microcontroller.  Sometimes you may need to have a way for the microcontroller to tell the test equipment what it has done to the peripheral or about to do so the test equipment can prepare to capture, this communication to the test equipment of course is yet another circuit that needs to be tested (yes you have a chicken and egg problem, that is normal).

Perform a test for every section until each section is tested, then load the real firmware onto the device or otherwise run the real firmware.

Comment: Thanks dwelch. I have these circuits in my board: 1. Power supply circuit to supply necessary  power to uC, to solenoid firing circuit and to charge Super capacitor
2. Signal conditioning circuitry.
3. USB interface circuitry. Any information related in this regard which i can refer to is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the power to the uc is generally not something you test with software on the uc other than to see the uc is alive and powered.

Comment: signal conditioning, is that incoming or outgoing?  in either case to test it you would need to create the bad signals that the conditioner filters out to see that it did it and make a test to verify that.

Comment: usb interface, can you connect to the usb, enumerate, communicate?